# Autocorrecting text entries based on predefined list

Tags: excel, vba

Problem is simple: I'm copying or typing in company names which need to be formatted in a certain way. For example, column one is:

```
A.G. Edwards Inc., New York 
Abbott Laboratories L.T.D., Los Angeles
Abercrombie & Fitch Co., Mars
ABM Industries Incorporated L.T.D., Venus
```

but the data which I receive is:

```
A.G. Edwards
Abbott Laboratories. 
Abercrombie & Fitch 
ABM Industries Incorporated.
```

What I'm looking for is a way to automate formatting by using predefined proper list which would be in another workbook or access database.

So when I type Abbot Laboratories it would autocorrect to proper format, or whats more often when I paste ABOTT LABORATORIES it would correct it.

- I'm not sure if autocorrect could do this because list would be really long 600+ entries, plus not always my input data is the same (sometimes I get Abbot Laboratories LTD, sometimes its Abbot Laboratories, los angeles), name is usually correct but rest changes.

I've googled extensively but nothing I found so far looks like it would help me.

So to recap: check text in one column and correct it to match large list of proper text entries.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would try something like this: have in some column your list and also have some part of text which will refer to full name in list column. Next have event listener (when sheet changes) which will compare part of string to what you inserted (via regexp) and if its match the referee text, replace changed cell with data from list column. I think it will make what you are looking for

Comment: Possibly use a vlookup... If you almost always have the first few letters, it should do really well. Just make sure to set the [range_lookup] to true!